# Split a two letter string in java

Tags: java, string, split

I am just trying to split a string into two smaller strings. It seems like it would be easy but for some reason I cannot figure it out. An example of what I am trying to split is this:

```
AA
BB
DD
FF
TT
EE
SE
GR
```

These values are currently in an ArrayList and I would like them to split into two arraylists

```
A                A
B                B
D                D
```

I tried this

```
prse = calls.get(t).split(""); //also tried prse = calls.get(t).split("", -1);
            call1.add(prse[0]);
            call2.add(prse[1]);
```

But it filled my arraylists with empty characters. (Printed []
[, ]
[, , ]
[, , , ]
[, , , , ])

So then I tried

```
    String split = calls.get(t).substring(0,1); //This is 285 that is puking
    String split2 = calls.get(t).substring(1,2);
                System.out.println(split);
                call1.add(split);
                System.out.println("1: " + call1);
                call2.add(split2);
                System.out.println("2: " + call2);
```

Which works up to a point but then dies a horrible death:

```
1: [F, P, T, B, F, D, S, G, G, G, Z, S, Q, E, F, H, L, P, O, L, G, B, V, F, W, Q, T, H, G, E, R, T, Y, C, G, D, C, H, C, A]
2: [o, G, U, U, Y, Y, T, T, T, T, T, R, E, S, G, J, H, C, H, H, H, G, C, J, H, D, G, J, H, D, R, G, V, C, G, V, V, D, V, V]

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
        at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1946)
        at print.Reader.ffy(Reader.java:285)
        at print2.Print2.main(Print2.java:48)
```

Can anyone suggest a better way to do this (Or explain to me what I am doing wrong)?
Notes:
I would like to put the split letters into their own, separate ArrayList String (due to later usage.)  so I would rather not charArray.

Comment: I think the `split` method is massive overkill here.  Have you tried using `substring`?

Comment: @templatetypedef He tried using `substring`.

Comment: I think you are parsing an empty string at the end

Comment: @User I think you have to show some more code what are you doing

Comment: Check for the length of the String in the ArrayList, if it has a size of 0 or 1, figure what you want to do but don't call substring method.

Comment: I believe @DanielCastro is correct; you're explicitly calling substring(0,1) and it's probably trying to perform it on a EoF character or something similar.  Try checking the length of the string first and only proceed if length=2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        prse = calls.get(t).split("");
        call1.add(prse[0]);
        call2.add(prse[1]);
```

when u split with blank string => "", the first string that u get is blank("").
so example : "AB" prse[0] = "", prse[1]="A" ,prse[2]="B"

Comment: Thanks for the info. I really probably should have figured that out. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
String inData = prse = calls.get(t);
call1.add("" + inData.charAt(0));
call2.add("" + inData.charAt(1));
```

This directly grabs the first and second characters and converts them to a string.

If you wanted an char array list you wouldn't have to convert to a String, depends on what you want to do with the output.

StringBuilder can .append a char, and toString the result.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
```

^^ means that the index 1 passed to the substring method is out of bounds, i.e. you have a string in your array (probably right after "AV") that has only zero or one character.

Also, "substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)" is a fine method for this, but why not use "charAt(int index)" instead?

Comment: This help me solve a secondary problem I was having. Some of them are indeed 0 or 1 characters long. Thanks so much.